# Bundle dependency could not be resolved due to missing constraint on import package, How to add jar dependency in a an osgi bundle using maven?

Tags: maven, jar, dependencies, osgi, opendaylight

I am new to maven.

I am trying to import a jar dependency (`com.jcraft.jsch`) in my opendaylight controller project. The code compiles successfully. But when the controller is run, it throws the following errors.

---

!ENTRY org.opendaylight.controller.samples.ssr 4 0 2013-10-11 10:25:14.624
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.opendaylight.controller.samples.ssr_0.4.0.SNAPSHOT [36]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: com.jcraft.jsch; version="0.0.0"
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolverError(AbstractBundle.java:1332)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.getResolutionFailureException(AbstractBundle.java:1316)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
2013-10-11 10:25:14.627 IST [org.opendaylight.controller.logging.bridge.internal.LogListenerImpl@190c63b2] ERROR o.o.c.logging.bridge.OSGI2SLF4J - Bundle:org.opendaylight.controller.samples.ssr Message:FrameworkEvent ERROR Exception:org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The bundle "org.opendaylight.controller.samples.ssr_0.4.0.SNAPSHOT [36]" could not be resolved. Reason: Missing Constraint: Import-Package: com.jcraft.jsch; version="0.0.0"

---

I have imported that package. The package org.opendaylight.controller.samples.ssr is added by me in it. Basically, I have modified one of the packages in samples.
The problem is I am trying to import one jar dependency com.jcraft.jsch in one of the classes in this package. But there is a problem with importing this jar.

I have been slogging after this issue for last couple of weeks. Any suggestions or solutions  please. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Package org.opendaylight.controller.samples.ssr is not available in any bundle or if it is available, it is not exported.

Comment: Thanks you :) Can you please look at it again? I have modified this query a little bit..

Comment: Can you telnet onto the equinox system? If yes, what does the command "packages com.jcraft.jsch" say? I think it is not in the OSGi container. If it is there, I will be surprised. It might be in one of your jars but are you sure it is listed in the Export-Package Manifest header? If it is in that jar and the package is listed, is that bundle in ACTIVE state (ss command in the console)?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue in OpenDaylight. Here's a solution that I figured out after some trial and error (Let me know if you find any step to be unnecessary):

The Maven dependency in your case would have, Group Id as **com.jcraft**, Artifact Id as **jsch**, Version as **0.1.31** (say) and Imported Package ias **com.jcraft.jsch**. Also, your OpenDaylight module is **org.opendaylight.controller.samples.ssr**.

In the file **distribution/opendaylight/opendaylight-osgi-launcher.launch** and **distribution/opendaylight/opendaylight-osgi-launcher-local.launch**, add your dependency and the module to the following tags:

```
...
<stringAttribute key="target_bundles" value="com.jcraft.jsch@default:default,ch.qos.logback.classic@default:default, ch.qos.logback.core@default:default ..."/>
.
.
<stringAttribute key="workspace_bundles" value="org.opendaylight.controller.samples.ssr@default:default,org.opendaylight.controller.arphandler@default:default, ..."/>
...
```

In file **distribution/opendaylight/opendaylight.target**, add a unit entry as,

```
...
<unit id="com.google.gson" version="2.1.0"/>
<unit id="com.jcraft.jsch" version="0.1.31"/>
...
```

In **distribution/p2site/pom.xml**, add the artifact entry as,

```
...
<artifact>
  <id>com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1</id>
  <transitive>false</transitive>
  <override>false</override>
</artifact>
<artifact>
  <id>com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.31</id>
  <transitive>false</transitive>
  <override>false</override>
</artifact>
...
```

In **commons/opendaylight/pom.xml**, add the dependency entry as,

```
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
  <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.31</version>
</dependency>
...
```

Do a complete OpenDaylight maven build and run. It should work fine. In case, this dependency has further chained dependencies you might get the error again. Import those dependencies the same way.